# Display items from List of type Object

Tags: arrays, spring, nativequery

i created a java method which contains an sql request than returns to me an array of items but it returns it as an Object , so when i want to display each item of that array or make some change to it it work because it's of type Object , is there any solution to do such thing ?

this is my java method :

```
    public List<Object> getlist(int idUser){
    List<Object> results = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT a.status_conformite, coalesce((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM analyses inner join ma_base on (analyses.mabase_id=ma_base.id) WHERE ma_base.user_id = u.id and analyses.status_conformite = a.status_conformite),0) As Status_Count FROM User u CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT status_conformite FROM analyses) a WHERE u.id =?").setParameter(1, idUser).getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

this is my Api where i want to make the changes :

```
@GetMapping("/stats/{id}")
public List<Object> stats(@PathVariable(value="id") int idUser){
    List<Object> myArray=analysesDao.getlist(idUser);
    return analysesDao.getlist(idUser);
}
```

i want to make some changes on the myArray variable but i didn't know how to do it

Comment: You should iterate the Object properties and do the changes that you want

Comment: Object is not a class that i created , it's a general type java.lang.Object

Comment: You have to create a class that will be used instead of Object, what columns the query will return?

Comment: haha i was just thinking to do the same thing :p , thank you anyway for your time

Comment: Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Yes , i did it before but i was too lazy to redo it :p